# I am doing a burger menu but my third stripe wont appear

Tags: html, css

I am doing css and my third stripe won't appear for some reason.

I have looked for spelling errors and mistakes but I keep coming back to the same problem even though firefox doesn't give me an html error(also i am not finished with toggle this is just styling)

```css
/*.hamburger-menu{
    display: none;
}*/
#menu_toggle{
    opacity: 0;
}
.menu_btn{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1;
}
.menu_btn > span,
.menu_btn > span::before,
.menu_btn > span::after{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #d11;
}
.menu_btn > span::before{
    content: '';
    top: -8px;
}
.menu_btn > span::after{
    top:8px;
}
.menu_box{
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 80px 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #eee;
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
```

```html
<div class="hamburger-menu">
<input type="checkbox" id="menu_toggle">
<label class="menu_btn" for="menu_toggle">
    <span></span>
</label>
<ul class="menu_box">
    <li class="menu_item" href="#">Home</li>
    <li class="menu_item" href="#">Our Products</li>
    <li class="menu_item" href="#">More About Us</li>
    <li class="menu_item" href="#">How To Use</li>
    <li class="menu_item" href="#">Become An Affiliate</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `.menu_btn > span::after` doesn't have `content` property.

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Your .menu_btn > span::after has no content. That's why it's not showing up.

```css
/*.hamburger-menu{
    display: none;
}*/
#menu_toggle{
    opacity: 0;
}
.menu_btn{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1;
}
.menu_btn > span,
.menu_btn > span::before,
.menu_btn > span::after{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #d11;
}
.menu_btn > span::before, .menu_btn > span::after{
    content: '';
    top: -8px;
}
.menu_btn > span::after{
    top:8px;
}
.menu_box{
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 80px 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #eee;
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
```

```html
<div class="hamburger-menu">
<input type="checkbox" id="menu_toggle">
<label class="menu_btn" for="menu_toggle">
    <span></span>
</label>
<ul class="menu_box">
    <li class="menu_item" href="#">Home</li>
    <li class="menu_item" href="#">Our Products</li>
    <li class="menu_item" href="#">More About Us</li>
    <li class="menu_item" href="#">How To Use</li>
    <li class="menu_item" href="#">Become An Affiliate</li>
</ul>
</div>
```